# Função RANK() ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Alguém poderia me explicar o que há errado com a minha sintaxe/uso da função de RANK?

Situação problema: 
"Faça um ranking de músicas por banda, de maneira que as músicas de maior
duração ocupem os primeiros lugares. Apresente nome da banda e da música e
posição no ranking."

```
SELECT MU.NOME, BA.NOME
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MU.TEMPO_DURACAO ORDER BY BA.NOME)
FROM MUSICA MU, BANDAS_E_ARTISTAS BA, BANDA BD
WHERE BA.ID = BD.ID
```

Comment: Parece falta a condição de join de "MUSICA" , gerando um prodoto cartesiano indevido.

Answer (score 0):

Bom parece que seu join está errado, você está unindo musica, bandas e artistas e bandas, mas só está fazendo o join entre as bandas e os artistas, mas as musicas estão sem nada na cláusula where. O ideal seria ter um `MU.id_banda = BD.id` ou algo do tipo.

Quanto ao rank, ele pede para quebrar por banda e ordenar por tempo, logo deveria ser algo assim:

```
SELECT MU.NOME, BA.NOME,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BA.NOME ORDER BY MU.TEMPO_DURACAO DESC)
FROM MUSICA MU, BANDAS_E_ARTISTAS BA, BANDA BD
WHERE BA.ID = BD.ID AND MU.BANDA_ID = BD.ID
```

Comment: Caso em que o perguntador some.